# this pointer passed to template from a virtual member function

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, this

I have a virtual function that is implemented in a base class A. 
This function has a loop in it. A derived class B is available but does not override the virtual function as the code is the same for any derived class.

Well, however, I need an additional condition check inside that virtual function (local_policy) that should be called depending on class type (base or derived).
Now, I could implement another virtual member function and override it in the derived class however as the call happens inside of a loop the virtual overhead should be minimized, so I thought I rather use a function template and specialize it for any derived classes.

Now the problem is that I am passing *this pointer to the function template from within foo() and the specialization is never called.
Is the this pointer in this certain case of type A instead of B? I would have guessed it is not and that my specialised function template would be called.

I appreciate any help!

```
template < typename T >
bool local_policy(const T* mtype) { return true; }

class A
{
   public: 
   virtual void foo()
   {
      for(..) { 
         if(local_policy(this)) //This will call the non-specialised template! Why?
         { /* do something */ }
      }
   }
   /* [...] */
}

class B : public A
{         
   /* [...] */
   //foo() is not overridden here
}

//Specialize the function template for class B
template <>
bool local_policy(const B* mtype) { return false; }

main()
{
   B* test = new B; if(!B) return;
   test->foo(); 
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Best

P.S.: I also tried some C++11 using a normal function and a global template with std::enable_if to only enable if it is a derived class. Doesn't matter, also that one is not called as I expected. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not allow dynamic dispatch based on argument types -- function overload resolution is always based on the *static* type of the expression.  In your example, the static type of `this` with always be `A *`, even when it points at a `B`, so your specialized function will never be called.

If you want dynamic dispatch, you must use a virtual function, and you can only dynamically dispatch based on the `this` argument, never any other arguments.  If you're worried about the overhead, you can hoist the dynamic call out of the loop and only call it once:

```
virtual bool local_policy() { return true; }
virtual void foo() {
    bool policy = local_policy();
    for (..) {
        if (policy) {
            /* do something */
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler can't ever do this optimization on its own, since it doesn't know that you'll never define a derived class that overrides the `local_policy` function with something that has side effects...

Comment: Hi! The first part of your answer actually solves my comprehension issue, so thanks for that!! Unfortunately it is not possible to get the policy check out of the loop as I need to pass local arguments to that policy function, that's why I wrote in my statement that I cannot make it a virtual function as it MUST retain in the loop (otherwise the question wouldn't have raised in the first place). thx